# How to change SystemTime format?

Tags: windows, datetime, time, windows-server-2008, gmt

In the event viewer in windows 2008, the events XML are showing this:

```
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-11-21T19:42:45.000Z" />
```

The time currently is 2011-11-21 14:42:45. I understand that the system time value is the GMT time.

**The question is** how can I change the format of the system time value in the events XML to be something similar to this **2011-11-21 14:42:45**?

Comment: The format you're asking for is not a valid XML date, where the one currently being shown in the XML is valid. Also, this is not a programming question, and therefore is off topic here.

Comment: There is nothing called a valid XML date. It depends on the XML schema XSD. I am asking if there is a way to change that. This is not a subjective question, it is a specific problem/question, so it is valid based on the question policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible to change the time format, it has to be on the GMT format.
Here is what I have found on
[Microsoft Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/08e21179-70b2-4159-a6c3-e39ca1454469), as well as this [thread](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/event-viewer-problem-395189.html).

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in my comment to the original question. :)